# CLI response doesn't specify what type of ingress traffic setting is selected in an Azure ContainerApp

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I'm working with Azure ContainerApps via CLI.

I'm trying to check what ingress traffic setting (**Allow all traffic / Limited to VNet / Limited to Container Apps Environment**) is allowed in my containerapp using the CLI.

Doing an `az containerapp list` lists the configuration of all the containerapps that are present.
From the obtained result, I know that "**properties.configuration.ingress.external**" tells me if public traffic is enabled but that is too generic in my case as that only talks about public access in general.

I also tried the `az containerapp show` command. That result doesn't help either.

Any help on this will be highly helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: which (/what type of) information are you trying to get ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the ingress traffic enabled for a container app? @Impulse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the type of the ingress traffic setting enabled for a container app, you can use the below commands with the `query` parameter.

Below command displays the whole set of ingress traffic features configured for a container app in `Json` format.

```
az containerapp ingress show -n newapca -g exampleRG1
```

***If you use the --query flag as shown, you can access only those specific settings.***

*Allow all Ip's:*

```
az containerapp ingress show -n newapca -g exampleRG1 --query external
```

*Limited to VNet:*

```
 az containerapp ingress show -n newapca -g exampleRG1 --query vNetname
```

[image]

You can check the access-restriction list of IP's of a container app with the below given command.

```
az containerapp ingress access-restriction list -n newapca -g exampleRG1
```

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/ingress/traffic?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-ingress-traffic-show) for the command structures.

*Note*: Use [az containerapp update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/ingress?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-ingress-update) with the `--set` flag to update from one setting to the other.

Comment: I know it has been a very long time but thanks a lot. Couldn't get back earlier due to an infinite list of other problems.